# Is it possible to implement Angular pages into an ABP project that uses MVC as UI?

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-mvc, abp

I’ve developed a web application using the community version of ABP Framework with MVC as UI.
I now have the need to implement an Angular page into the application.
Is it possible to do it, or to at least make a menù link that redirects to an already existing Angular application? Or can I only use the already implemented MVC UI?